# C# XML Serialization: Attributes and Namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-namespaces

In a logging structure, I have a list of states and within each state, there are several fields, each having a few attributes. Some of those fields have a attributes with the same name, but with different types, i.e. int versus float. Notice the 'timestamp' attribute in this particular example:

```
public class DroneState
{
    [XmlAttribute("timestamp")]
    public int timestamp;

    ...
}

public class SensorState
{
    [XmlAttribute("timestamp")]
    public float timestamp;

    ...
}

public class CombinedState
{
    [XmlElement("DroneState")]
    public DroneState droneState = null;
    [XmlElement("Sensor")]
    public SensorState sensorState = null;
}

public class FlightLog
{
    [XmlElement("States"), XmlArrayItem("State")]
    public List<CombinedState> states = new List<CombinedState>();

    public static void SaveToFile(FlightLog flightLog, string file)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FlightLog));
        string xml = string.Empty;
        // serialize and return string
        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, flightLog);
            xml = writer.ToString();
        }

        File.WriteAllText(file, xml);
    }
}
```

Using this code to generate an XML document, I get struck with the following exception:

> InvalidOperationException: The XML attribute named 'timestamp' from namespace '' is already present in the current scope. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the attribute.

This is something I could have expected, but I don't seem to be capable of solving it. Whatever I try with regards to adding a namespace for each attribute, it keeps complaining that the attributes are allocated in the '' namespace.

What are the steps to take in making sure that each timestamp attribute is placed in its own namespace?

Comment: Could you provide code to reproduce your issue? Because changing   `[XmlElement("States"), XmlArrayItem("State")]` to `[XmlArray("States"), XmlArrayItem("State")]` alone makes everything to serialize-deserialize fine, without namespace issues

Comment: @Shorstok I thought I created a minimal example above extracted from my larger project, and it seems indeed that the situation depicted above works just fine when I set it up running in Fiddle. So there is indeed no issue to be seen here. Thanks for this sanity check!

Answer (score 0):

You could just give the different signatures/types different attribute names

```
public class DroneState
{
    [XmlAttribute("timestampInt")]
    public int timestamp;

    //...
}

public class SensorState
{
    [XmlAttribute("timestampFloat")]
    public float timestamp;

    //...
}
```

or timestampDrone / timestampSensor for that matter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although it is a valid solution to the problem, it's not the type of solution I was looking for. In certain situations you indeed have the control to alter the output format of the document, but that's not always the case. So I was specifically looking for a solution involving namespaces.
In the comments below my question, @Shorstok pointed out that there is no actual issue to be seen in the code posted.

Answer (score 0):

In the code posted above, no actual problems are defined. It compiles and runs fine and I though that this was a minimal example of the issue I thought I encountered. I identified the cause of the issue to be 2 fields writing to the same attribute, which gave reason to exception being thrown. This was solely caused by a lack of oversight on my part.

The code giving the issue:

```
[XmlAttribute("timestamp")]
public long timestamp;

[Quite a bit of other members...]

[XmlAttribute("timestamp")]
public float acceleration;
```

Letting the `acceleration` member write to an appropriate attribute solved the problem.